# How to add automatic input for a compiled C++ file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm just wondering if there is any way to automatically pass input sequence for any compiled C++ code in Visual Studio Code in Mac.

What I'm trying to say is, for example, I have compiled the following simple code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a + b << endl;
}
```

I'm looking for an extension where I can input a couple of numbers as the input of this program so that after I run this "a.out" it will automatically take input from that input set and give me the output on the terminal or visual studio console.Thanks!

Comment: Simply run your program like `a.out < input.txt` with file content like `1 2`.

Comment: And you could also write some shell script to help you

Comment: Or you can simply pipe the numbers to your program, e.g. `echo 1 2 | your.exe`. You should be sure to validate `cin >> a >> b;` succeeds before calling `cout`.

Comment: This behavior is a common task in unit testing, so you can likely find applicable resources by researching that field of test runners.

Comment: Thanks! Either of the solutions will help for me :)

Comment: @S.M. can you explain in detail